# ASP.NET web application - WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd files - Loading time issue

Tags: asp.net, loading, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

.
Hi,
      We are building an ASP.NET application with C#.net as language.

Here, when the IIS renders a page & when we analyze the page code with YSlow tool it shows many WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd files (as we are referring many script files in the page).

Server-side code is executing fast but loading of these .axd files is taking time. 
So would you please guide me on this, if there is a way to optimize or suppress these axd files?

If would be great if you could also provide a reference document or web references (If needed).

Many Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: A very very similar question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505416/how-do-i-combine-webresource-axd-and-scriptresource-axd-files-so-as-to-result-in

Answer (score 5):

[WebResource.axd](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442) and [ScriptResource.axd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.scriptresourcehandler.aspx) references are embedded resources in the .NET Framework. WebResource.axd scripts are probably for web forms and validation while ScriptResource.axd is for [ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/).

You can combine the ScriptResource.axd scripts into one include by using the [ToolkitScriptManager](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/OtherNeatStuff.aspx) (part of the [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Default.aspx)).

I'm not sure of a way to combine the WebResource.axd scripts.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505416/how-do-i-combine-webresource-axd-and-scriptresource-axd-files-so-as-to-result-in) for more on combining scripts.

Answer (score 5):

jrummell is right on but if you want a detailed explanation of ways to improve that I would suggest this link:

[ASP.NET AJAX Performance Improvement](http://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/aspnet-ajax-performance/)

It gives detailed information on script combining, turning on caching, and etc.  Trust me it will help you speed it up.

Comment: I have tried all options given on your link but no success. Could you please look at this and help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198461/combining-multiple-calls-to-scriptresource-axd

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm a couple years late here, but for all you googlers out there, I just pushed a new release of my on the fly js/css minifier/merger [RequestReduce](https://github.com/mwrock/RequestReduce) that successfully merges Webresource and scriptresource files at run time.