# Shorter names for /ScriptResource.axd and/or /WebResource.axd in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

My page loads scripts and css from some custom assembly. For now, I use the ScriptManager to add scripts to the page (its CompositeScript) and the page's `ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl()` for css files. So, on the page(s) my scripts are referenced by /ScriptResource.axd and css are referenced by /WebResource.axd. Works fine except the fact that those URLs look really ugly. Is there any manageable way to replace those urls with my own fake paths without moving/hosting script/css physical files somewhere? Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who's going to see the URLs? Do you have a concern relating to SEO or some other factor?

Comment: Not really. I guess I'm just trying to find out if it's possible at all. I coded my last project in MVC and co-workers were quite impressed how clean that HTML looked. That's the root of the question. And no, I can't move this project to MVC :)

Comment: You'd have to create your own HTTP handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Filter` to find all the `WebResource.axd` and `ScriptResource.axd` src'es and replace them with something you like better. You then need a `IHttpHandler`, as Brian comments, that understands your new url-format and returns the same content as the original axd-files would have.

You should also look into combining all those script and css resources to save requests from the browser. [How do I combine WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd files so as to result in less requests to my ASP.NET server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505416/how-do-i-combine-webresource-axd-and-scriptresource-axd-files-so-as-to-result-in)