# Which javascript scriptreference is linked to each ScriptResource.axd?

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, composite

[Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html#extension-rel) is saying we should [combine external JavaScript](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html#CombineExternalJS). Fair enough.

I know that the way to do this is to use a CompositeScript tag inside asp:ScriptManager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
   <CompositeScript>
      <Scripts>
         <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
         <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.Calendar.CalendarBehavior.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
         < ... />
      </Scripts>
    </CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

What I don't know is which script references to add. In my page I have lots of

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=big-string-here" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**How do I discover what `<asp:ScriptReference Name="x" Assembly="Y" />` tags I should add to the CompositeScript tag?**

There's a usercontrol out there with this specific aim, and we even have already used it before, but I can't find it again o Google.

---

**EDIT**

The usercontrol I was looking for is [ScriptReferenceProfiler](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/13356). [How to use it.](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=524)
I still accepted the answer bellow because it may help someone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you use AJAX Toolkit's [ToolkitScriptManager](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Walkthrough/OtherNeatStuff.aspx) then it would anyway combine all ScriptResource and WebResource scripts by default (you need not have to mention these). See these related posts: 
[How do I combine WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd files so as to result in less requests to my ASP.NET server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505416/how-do-i-combine-webresource-axd-and-scriptresource-axd-files-so-as-to-result-in)

In .NET4, ScriptManager should also able to do the same: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a great point and good advice, but it do not answer the asked question. I tried ToolkitScriptManager but unfortunately it was incompatible with something else.

Comment: @tiagoniu, I understand that its not answer to your specific question (but I believe that it solves the actual problem) - the issue with adding script resources & web resources manually is not actually about the discovery of resources being used but its more about maintenance - what if new version of control comes up that uses different set of resources or new control has been added to page etc. A full proof solution would involve discovery of registered script resources - thats exactly is happening in above solutions.